# Is my raspberry Pi dead

Tags: power, usb-power, boot-issues, fuses

I tried a circuit with raspberry pi to drive a motor, so there was 12 V at the circuit I used it with. I might have wired it in a wrong way for a short while and I immediately shut the power down.

At the moment, when I try connect it to power, PWR light is not on, ACT is green, its not turned on and the processor starts to heat immediately.

Does that mean it is permanently damaged? Is there anything I can do?

Comment: What made you think connecting 12 volts to the PI was safe?

Comment: I didnt intend to but probably there was a short in the entire circuit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's dead. It should have been okay if the board was completely silent (blown polyfuse, wait a few hours) but you mentioned that the SOC heats up immediately. Therefore, it's most probably dead.

Comment: Is there anything I can do to fix it (by replacing a part somehow for example) or is it entirely disposable now...

Comment: @OE1 Keep it as a reminder for yourself or for other people. This is if I were you.

Comment: @OE1 If you somehow have a few BCM2835 (or BCM2836 for RPi2) lying around, you could try to replace the current SOC while you wait for another Pi or after you get another pi.