# 15V to the GPIOs: Blown the PI?

Tags: gpio, rip

So, I am using the Pi on a robotics project and, while doing so, bumped my +15V source (wall transformer, rated for 400mA and 15V) into one of the pin inputs. It touched for <0.5s, but now connecting the monitor and power gives a blank screen (not the test screen, just blank, and monitor goes to sleep after 5s) and the red and green LEDs are solid, not flashing.

Did I blow the Pi, or will it possibly work after I let the polyfuse settle for 4-5 days?

Thanks

Comment: Only time will tell, you can wait a day or two and try again. If you are lucky you only killed the pin. BTW .5s is an eternity  in electronics.

Comment: This parrot is no more! He has ceased to be! 'E's expired and gone to meet 'is maker! (Read: it's most likely dead. The poly fuse does not protect GPIO pins.)

Comment: Related: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/38352/24224

Comment: I don't think waiting would do any good. You just shot 15V 400mA into an unprotected pin that can only handle 3.3v 15mA.

Comment: As I've said to someone before, you should keep it in order to remind yourself and others not to mess up in the future.

Comment: The problem was not that I plugged the the wire in wrong, it was that I was using a L293D driver so the motor power in and the logic input pins were right next to each other, and my fingers were a little jittery...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I reckon you have a dead Pi.

The 15V was inserted directly into the Pi, it did not go through the polyfuse, so the polyfuse will not have given the limited protection it provides.

If you have a meter (carefully) measure the voltage at the Pi 5V pin.  If it is 5V then the polyfuse has not operated.

Comment: That's kind of what I was thinking, but I guess I can still hope. Any chance I could save the SD card if I get another Pi (all my code is on there)?

Comment: I don't know if the SD card would have been damaged or not.  You could put it in a reader and check if you can see the FAT partition.  If that is okay it is likely the ext4 Linux partition will also be okay.

Comment: I don't think measuring anything would do any good. He just shot 15V 400mA into an unprotected pin that can only handle 3.3v 15mA.

Comment: Yup. Dead sucker. I pulled out the SD and read it, and the files were corrupted. Not sure if that's because of blowing it, or because I had them open at the time I blew it.

Comment: No, what corrupted the files was that I tried to read them with Windows. Two more dead Pi's later (a variety of unfortunate accidents), I have learned that the SD card always survives and you can just stuff it into the next Pi.