# Faint PWR LED, doesn't boot

Tags: gpio, boot, pi-2, power, power-supply

I've just installed Raspbian to my new RPi2 B+. Shutdown and connect Adafruit Neopixel Ring (3 connectors: 4th pin - 5v, 6th pin - GND, 12th pin - DATA IN) and boot the RPi. Then it has reset itself and hasn't booted anymore. Red pwr led lights faint, and the green just a bit. Power supply is 5V, 2A.

Edit: After all found the recommendations to not supply Neopixels by the 5V rpi's output. **The question is - is it possible to recover RPI or better throw to trash?**

Comment: Hello and welcome. Do you have a multi-meter available to check the voltage of your power-supply?

Comment: Hello, unfortunately not.

Comment: Do you have a reference WRT how you decided it should be hooked up that way?   Supplying 5V and then attaching a GPIO pin directly may not have been wise.  https://learn.adafruit.com/neopixels-on-raspberry-pi/wiring

Comment: Are you also using the Adafruit "[neopixels-on-raspberry-pis](https://learn.adafruit.com/neopixels-on-raspberry-pi)" article for reference at all?

Comment: Does it boot up okay without the Neopixels?  If so, there is insufficient power.

Comment: Ah, goldilocks's link is a page within the article I quoted...! 8-/

Comment: @goldilocks no, my fault. reading in description "no external choke resistors are required making the design slim. Power the whole thing with 5VDC (4-7V works) and you're ready to rock." made me wrongly sure about out-of-box of this.

Comment: @joan no, RPi doesn't work at all.

Comment: [This](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-neopixel-uberguide) page lists supply requirements for various rings.  I note that the original article I linked to says: **is not confirmed to work on RPi2** - given that it does things using the PWM outputs (and I'm not sure that the pins for that are constant across all Pi?) that may be the basis for the reports that they refer to there: "The[re] are some reports that this library does not work with the new Raspberry Pi 2. Be warned that the library is not confirmed to work with the Pi 2 hardware yet--only the first generation Pi is known to work."

Comment: I don't know what's considered acceptible behavior ( @joan ? ) , but it could be that when power is first supplied that PWM "input" gets driven high.   Beware using 3.3V logic on a 5V powered device.

Comment: Another possibility is that a 16 light neopixel ring draws one amp, and so you may have partially blown the pi's main polyfuse during boot.  The good news is it should bounce back. Leave it unplugged for a day or two then try again (without the ring...) https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfuse

Comment: I've just measured F1 resistance and it seems to be normal ~1.3 Ohms.

Comment: And when i power it up it is about inf (300M)

Comment: @DamianPrzygodzki Did it boot?

Comment: @PandaLion98 no, still the red led is glowing really weakly and it doesnt boot.

Comment: @DamianPrzygodzki And the board power supply works correctly, right? Did/can you check the voltages?

Comment: @PandaLion98 Yeah, i tried and it bit confuses me. The voltage on pins 3.3V and 5V are okay (despite the super high resistance on f1). PP1 - PP3 && PP2-PP5 are 5V. And didnt find any informations, how to test farther more.

Comment: And one more symptom. And it not sounds great. The SOC after turning on , heats up immediately.

Comment: @DamianPrzygodzki Tsk tsk. http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/38352/24224

Answer (score 2):

Remove all the neopixel bits.  If the pi boots with no issues then thank the relevant god(s) and continue.

If the pi does not boot, do not worry.  You have made your sacrifice of magic smoke - buy a new pi.

Edit to add:  Check really carefully that the pins you soldered to the Neopixel Ring are what you think they are.  If mixed them up... magic smoke risk.

Comment: All of that was discussed in comments above. Not helpful answer.

Comment: What was discussed in the comments was the relative wisdom of using a neopixel at 5v on a pi.  I was trying to answer the question of  "Do I need a new pi?", as per edited question.

Either a pi works...or you fried it.